# -[NSNull _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20dfcd8

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad

i know, this is strange but,

```
-[NSNull _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20dfcd8
```

i found the problem, while using fb graphAPI.

It was in this line of code:

```
[tempValues setObject:textFieldBeingEdited forKey:tagAsNum];
```

I want to change it to

```
[tempValues setObject:textFieldBeingEdited.text forKey:tagAsNum];
```

but i dont find this anywhere in my code.

Do anybody hv idea, in which class it can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that `textFieldBeingEdited` is either `nil` or `NSNull`. I'm not certain what `tempValues` is, so I don't know if its `setObject:forKey:` automatically converts `nil` to `NSNull`.